# Tips for writing a contemporary story

Tags: creative-writing, fiction, genre, novella

I have a couple ideas for an upcoming novella that I am writing - one that I am quite excited about happens to fit into the contemporary fiction category. I don't consider myself to be a contemporary writer as I am more experienced in the post-apocalyptic/sci-fi genre.
The plot may lead more towards the romance side too, which terrifies me as I have NEVER written a romance arc, but I am intrigued by the challenge!

Does anybody have any tips on the dos and don'ts of the contemporary world? What should I avoid? And any advice on how to make the characters as realistic as possible would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi, you need to narrow the scope of your question to something that is answerable. It is currently way too broad, and opinion-based.